# PHP sort input textarea list into numbered list

Tags: php, forms

I have a form text area that I want users to paste data into, which then when submitted is processed with some PHP and returns the list but numbered every carraige return.

Eg, user inputs;

```
Ben
Chris
Morris
```

PHP returns;

```
1=Ben
2=Chris
3=Morris
```

Tried some preg_replace_callback technique but couldn't fathom it. Not too familiar with how it works though;

```
$list = $_POST["list"]; $count = 0;
preg_replace_callback('\r\n', 'rep_count', $list);

function rep_count($matches) {
    global $count;
    return '<br />' . $count++;
    }

echo $list;
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump` the content from the form in PHP?

Comment: couldnt you explode on "\n" and loop through? Appending the number

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple errors:

```
preg_replace_callback('\r\n', 'rep_count', $list);
                      ^^^^^^
```

Your pattern is incorrect - it's missing the delimiters, and should be `/\r\n/`. As well, using `'`-quoted strings for the pattern makes the `\r` and `\n` just be escaped alphabetical characters - `'`-quoted strings have no "metachars" like newlines and carriage returns.

Basically you need

```
preg_replace_callback("/\r\n/", 'rep_count', $list);
```

Note the `"` quotes, and the `/` delimeters.

Comment: no idea if it'd matter, but try moving the function definition to BEFORE the preg call. definition order normally doesn't matter in php, but who knows... maybe for preg callbacks it does.

Comment: Thanks, did that before reading comment and its looking good, now gotta work out how to display the list properly